# Timezone conversion in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to convert this GMT format to EST in xslt 1.0.

```
  <Date>Mon, 11 Aug 2009 13:15:10 GMT</Date>
```

is there any of doing that?

Comment: It's a pity the producer of that xml data didn't bother looking up the standard date format in xml.

Comment: This person implemented a separate script to do so: http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/199910/post70080.html

Not sure if that's what you are looking for...

Comment: Very good question (+1). @Fredrik-Mörk, @NinjaCat: See my answer for a pure (and complete) XSLT 1.0 solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a pure XSLT solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" >
 <xsl:import href=
  "C:\Program Files\Marrowsoft\Xselerator25\Samples\Libraries\datetime_lib.xsl"/>
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:param name="pnewZone" select="'EST'"/>

 <my:zones>
   <zone name="GMT" offset="+00:00"/>
   <zone name="EST" offset="-05:00"/>
 </my:zones>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="vDay" select=
   "substring-before(substring-after(., ' '), ' ')
   "/>

   <xsl:variable name="vMonthName" select=
   "substring-before(substring-after(., concat($vDay, ' ')), ' ')
   "/>

   <xsl:variable name="vYear" select=
   "substring-before(substring-after(., concat($vMonthName, ' ')), ' ')
   "/>

   <xsl:variable name="vTime" select=
   "substring-before(substring-after(., concat($vYear, ' ')), ' ')
   "/>

   <xsl:variable name="vMonth" select=
   "substring-before(
       substring($default-month-names,
                 string-length(substring-before($default-month-names,
                                                $vMonthName)
                               )-2),
       ']'
                    )
    "/>


  <xsl:variable name="vZone"
   select="substring-after(., concat($vTime, ' '))"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vzoneOffset" select=
   "document('')/*/my:zones/*[@name=$vZone]/@offset"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vnewzoneOffset" select=
   "document('')/*/my:zones/*[@name=$pnewZone]/@offset"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vDateTimeUTC" select=
   "concat($vYear, '-', $vMonth, '-', $vDay, 'T', $vTime, 'Z', $vzoneOffset)"/>

  <xsl:call-template name="local-to-local">
    <xsl:with-param name="datetime" select="$vDateTimeUTC"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="local-offset" select="$vnewzoneOffset"/>
  </xsl:call-template>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Date>Mon, 11 Aug 2009 13:15:10 GMT</Date>
```

**the desired, correct result is produced**:

```
2009-08-11T08:15:10Z-05:00
```

**Do note**:

1. **I am using the `datetime_lib.xsl` template library of Martin Rowlinson**. This library is part of the **[XSelerator](http://sf.net/projects/xselerator)**, which at present is a free product and can be downloaded at SourceForge.
2. **All processing in the above code is to prepare the parameters** to the `local-to-local` template from the imported library.
3. **I found a bug in `local-to-local` and corrected it**. Replace on line 1143 the following:

   ```
   <xsl:when test="($offset != 0) and ($new-offset != 0)">
   ```

with

```
    <xsl:when test="($offset != 0) or ($new-offset != 0)">
```

4. **The transformation of the result to the initial dateTime format is left as exercise** to the reader :)

Comment: Thanks, but for now i am going with C#.
Thanks again for all ur time.

Comment: dimitre, do you have a link to the datetime_lib.xsl you used in this question?

Comment: @user1130511: Unfortunately, the XSelerator project is no longer available on sourceforge.net. If you find somewhere on the net a newer version (nevermind it could be a trial version) and unzip it, this file can be found in the directory tree.

Comment: What about daylight saving time or GMT-4? How can we handle that automatically?